# Importing modules in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I`m working with the tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1026938/AngularJS-Getting-Started-with-Visual-Studio
and get the problem  this line:

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap, NgFor} from "angular2/angular2";
```

and I got the problem in  this line:
TS2307  Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'
I have exactly same files and folders, as in tutorial.
I try "typings/angular2/angular2", but this also didn`t help.

Comment: How did you install angular? npm?

Comment: either you install wrong angular2 setup or i suggest you to start with very basic project structure from Angular2 5 min quickstart. may b it will help you to find the error you getting.

Answer (score 0):

See the step-4 in [your-tutorial-link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1026938/AngularJS-Getting-Started-with-Visual-Studio). These settings are required for visual studio to detect the module.

[image]

Comment: I have set this option CommonJS, this is not the cause of the problem.